# Using Help&Manual with ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

I’m trying to connect a Help&Manual project to ClearCase. Clicking the “Check Version Control System” button reveals

> The Version Control Provider DLL connection was successful. The internal version of "ClearCase" is 1.1.

(Written in a reassuringly green color.) However, I tried several ways, and none succeeded: New project, existing project, in dynamic and in snapshot view, checked in and not, checked out and not.
I guess the answer is “does not work”. Could somebody please confirm? Or any other experiences?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of that app and the error message to illustrate that case? In other words, what is a "Help&Manual project"?

Comment: @VonC: http://www.helpandmanual.com, can create (you already might have guessed) help files. It claims it can directly communicate with SCCAPI compatible (“Microsoft Source Control API”) systems, and with the message I cited I guessed ClearCase is SCCAPI compatible. No useful error messages, really. I wanted to ask just in case somebody already figured this out.

Comment: And what ClearCase version are you using? On what type of server?

Comment: @VonC: ClearCase 7.1.2.9 on Win7 x64. No idea what server, and I’d like to avoid asking our admins *sic*

Answer (score 1):

That could be heavely dependent on the version of the ClearCase you are using.

A document like "[About SCC compliance and Rational ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21126483)" only mentions ClearCase 7.0 and 7.0.1, for instance.

If it works with Visual Studio but not with HelpAndManual, the workaround would be to manage the files in a snapshot view through the ClearCase interface directly, instead of through this SCCAPI integration.